# Compact $G_\delta$ subsets of locally compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $F$ is a closed subset thereof.
Then of course $F$ is also locally compact and Hausdorff.
Let $K$ be a subset of $F$, and suppose that $K$ is a compact $G_\delta$ with respect to $F$.
Clearly $K$ is compact as a subset of $X$.
Must it be a $G_\delta$ with respect to $X$?

Comment: wait...taking $X=[0,\omega_1]$ linearly ordered space, and $F=K=\{\omega_1\}$ is a counterexample, right??

Comment: Thanks. You're right. This answers my stated question. I will be posting a follow-up shortly.

Comment: The follow-up question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067751/baire-sets-in-locally-compact-hausdorff-spaces.